How to Create a New Document Set in SharePoint from PowerApps (customized) form?
I have a PowerApps form (customized from SharePoint library), which I need to basically mimic SharePoint's "Create New Document Set" action.  It serves as an intake form, and multi-level approval (approvers will revisit the submitted form frequently to update), and it's supposed to create a new document set.  Each video I find online have the steps in Power Automate to do this, except I don't see "Ask in PowerApps", so I have no idea what I would put for "folder Path", etc.  Is there a way I can have the user fill out the 10 or so fields in the form, create a new item in that Library, and create a new Document set?
Thank you!
